# Why is eating meat haram?

Tags: halal-haram, meat

As everybody knows, back in time, meat couldn’t be conserved properly and this led to major diseases affecting people, so that it was highly recommended to let as much as blood out the animals before eating them (since blood attracted bacteria). Now, technology has evolved, we have fridges, we have conservations techniques and we can keep meat and everything else "fresh" for a long time.
My Question is: Why hasn't also our religion evolved like everything else had?
Why are we always attached to rules that at this time wont have any bad effect on us. Isn't everything that is made haram in the quu'ran made by the purpose of avoid it since it's bad for us.
How can eating meat that is healthy and clean bad for us in anyway?

Comment: It sounds like you don't know much about Islam... http://www.islamforlife.co.uk/haram%20list.htm There's a site that explains what kinds of food are Haram in Islam. I'm sorry to say, but it's not that hard to type in Google: "Haram food in Islam"... Do some research first, before asking questions, please. And @masfenix, why is this a "good" question?

Comment: @TruthSeeker You've misunderstood the question. He's not asking what foods are haram. He's asking *why* certain foods/methods are haram. For example, chicken is permissible to eat only if slaughtered in a certain way. He's asking why that is still necessary especially if you combine scientific knowledge with it. It's a good question because it begs for an answer that challenges the current view. In other words, one must realize that these methods (slaughtering methods) have short comings, and they aren't actually required anymore.

Comment: That's very simple. God COMMANDS us to do so. He COMMANDS us not to do what we are not allowed to do. And He tells us what we ARE allowed to do. We are Muslims, and "Muslim" means: "someone who submits his will to the will of God". It's never, ever, about what we think. He wants us to kill animals in His Name, and in His name alone, because you're killing a living creature that He created. God set these rules, so God knows best. Drinking blood is bad for you, in case you didn't know. Eating pork is bad for you, in case you didn't know. Eating and drinking, what He forbade is ALWAYS bad.

Comment: Everything that God told us to do, when we do it, it will wind up as a gift. Everything that God told us NOT to do, when we do it, it will wind up as a disease. If you want me to give you some examples, hit me up.

Comment: @TruthSeeker You are not understanding the point. (we will also have to move this to chat if the discussion continues). You can still mention God's name using modern slaughter techniques. In fact, this is exactly what they do in Western countries. The act of manually slaughtering, however, is inhumane. It's just moving forward with society and bringing our religion with us - bearing in mind that we shouldn't change God's will. It's just a matter of whether people are willing to change their deeply held beliefs.

Comment: But OUR belief, IS what God wants us to do. God commands, and we must obey. We have no right to change His commands. No right. We are allowed to innovate, EXCEPT if it goes against the will of God. It's that simple.

Comment: Can you please clarify your question. I think this is what you're lookin for. "**[scientific reason for why is Islamic method of Slaughtering animals better](http://www.themodernreligion.com/misc/an/an_slaughter.htm)**"

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry I can't give you an honest answer, most of what I'll say will be my personal (non-religious) opinion.

> Why hasn't also our religion evolved like everything else had?

I think many factors come into this. The major one would be, if Allah really does exist and did send Islam, then how can a being with finite wisdom know more than a Being with infinite wisdom. If we change the law and we are wrong, that is to say we are worse off, then we will be punished for it. So I think fear of God and uncertainty of being right comes into play.

As many Muslims believe Islam is perfect, and therefore nothing should be added or taken away, evolution of the religion through enlightenment or otherwise goes against the idea Islam is perfect.

But I think other factors may also come into play. For example, trying to evolve religion may get you killed or harassed. A London Imam had received death threats for his view on the Theory of Evolution and women's rights to refuse the veil[1]. This is nothing compared to trying to change religion, how bad do you think that would be?

To be honest, as much as I want to change parts of Islam (such as slavery) I'm not religious, nor do I know much about my religion, so I don't think I qualify as being in a good position to suggest evolution of religion is good. Which may be the excuse for many who would like to see change.

That said, I do agree with many parts of Islam (at least of what our beloved Prophet followed) that will still hold true for today. Since I agree with most of the religion, should I seek to change the parts I feel are wrong?

Apologies for not truly answering your question. I would have preferred to comment but my reputation doesn't allow it.

---

[1] The Guardian: http://www.theguardian.com/world/2011/mar/06/usama-hasan-london-imam-death-threats-evolution

Answer (score 1):

Not everything that is haram is bad for us. IMO religion is faith based, we are suppose to follow what Allah has ordained for us Halal and what was ordained haram without asking the reason why or changing such laws if those reasons don't deem necessary.

For example, take pork. Now a days, pork can be easily correctly slaughtered and cooked to healthy perfection, does that mean it is not haram anymore? The same goes for meat that was slaughtered by people of the none Abrahamic religion, does it mean we can eat their meat?

The same goes for wine, there are many studies which show the complete opposite, that drinking a little amount of certain wines are good for your body.

Personally, I think the reasoning behind this is that the bad outweighs the good.

Take drinking as an example. If taking in moderation it good be good for you, but ultimately that is not the case and more bad happens from it. The same goes for pork, yes in modern countries it is clean but in the Majority of the world (3rd world countries) it is still a dilemma. We also see that pork causes the spread of many disease like the swine flu.